# Gitolite3 over http selinux permissions

Tags: selinux, gitolite

I'm trying to install gitolite3 on Centos6.4. It works, I can ssh and, after some trouble, I can also read, such as clone, through http and httpd. I am re-enabling selinux into permissive mode, that I disabled earlier for better testing, and the following errors appear in /etc/log/audit/audit.log.

I admit, I am a novice with selinux, and although I am very keen and started to seriously learn how selinux works, this is too much for me to interpret. Is there someone that can deduct from these messages which commands I have to run, permissions I have to somehow allow with best practice for online security in mind ?

..I will also mark answers as useful if you know and post of some amazing online selinux guides with security diagrams of how selinux ticks.

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.484:680): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=12882 comm="gitolite-shell" name="gitolite3" dev=sdb2 ino=264170 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.484:680): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=12882 comm="gitolite-shell" path="/var/lib/gitolite3/.gitolite.rc" dev=sdb2 ino=262551 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1375647504.484:680): arch=c000003e syscall=4 success=yes exit=0 a0=6d4d70 a1=6ab130 a2=6ab130 a3=18 items=0 ppid=4653 pid=12882 auid=4294967295 uid=650 gid=650 euid=650 suid=650 fsuid=650 egid=650 sgid=650 fsgid=650 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="gitolite-shell" exe="/usr/bin/perl" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.484:681): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=12882 comm="gitolite-shell" name=".gitolite.rc" dev=sdb2 ino=262551 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.484:681): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=12882 comm="gitolite-shell" name=".gitolite.rc" dev=sdb2 ino=262551 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1375647504.484:681): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=5 a0=a365f0 a1=0 a2=1b6 a3=30ce11dd40 items=0 ppid=4653 pid=12882 auid=4294967295 uid=650 gid=650 euid=650 suid=650 fsuid=650 egid=650 sgid=650 fsgid=650 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="gitolite-shell" exe="/usr/bin/perl" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.484:682): avc:  denied  { ioctl } for  pid=12882 comm="gitolite-shell" path="/var/lib/gitolite3/.gitolite.rc" dev=sdb2 ino=262551 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1375647504.484:682): arch=c000003e syscall=16 success=no exit=-25 a0=5 a1=5401 a2=7fff4ea63d90 a3=48 items=0 ppid=4653 pid=12882 auid=4294967295 uid=650 gid=650 euid=650 suid=650 fsuid=650 egid=650 sgid=650 fsgid=650 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="gitolite-shell" exe="/usr/bin/perl" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.498:683): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=12882 comm="gitolite-shell" name=".gitolite" dev=sdb2 ino=264248 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1375647504.498:683): arch=c000003e syscall=4 success=yes exit=0 a0=6d4d70 a1=6ab130 a2=6ab130 a3=706d6f63 items=0 ppid=4653 pid=12882 auid=4294967295 uid=650 gid=650 euid=650 suid=650 fsuid=650 egid=650 sgid=650 fsgid=650 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="gitolite-shell" exe="/usr/bin/perl" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.498:684): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=12882 comm="gitolite-shell" path="/var/lib/gitolite3/repositories/testing.git" dev=sdb2 ino=264285 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1375647504.498:684): arch=c000003e syscall=4 success=yes exit=0 a0=6d4d70 a1=6ab130 a2=6ab130 a3=31 items=0 ppid=4653 pid=12882 auid=4294967295 uid=650 gid=650 euid=650 suid=650 fsuid=650 egid=650 sgid=650 fsgid=650 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="gitolite-shell" exe="/usr/bin/perl" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.521:685): avc:  denied  { append } for  pid=12882 comm="gitolite-shell" name="gitolite-2013-08.log" dev=sdb2 ino=264307 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1375647504.521:685): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=a3af00 a1=441 a2=1b6 a3=30ce11dd40 items=0 ppid=4653 pid=12882 auid=4294967295 uid=650 gid=650 euid=650 suid=650 fsuid=650 egid=650 sgid=650 fsgid=650 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="gitolite-shell" exe="/usr/bin/perl" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.651:686): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=12886 comm="git-upload-pack" name="refs" dev=sdb2 ino=264308 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1375647504.651:686): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=12886 comm="git-upload-pack" name="refs" dev=sdb2 ino=264308 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:gitosis_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1375647504.651:686): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=675482 a1=90800 a2=675486 a3=0 items=0 ppid=12885 pid=12886 auid=4294967295 uid=650 gid=650 euid=650 suid=650 fsuid=650 egid=650 sgid=650 fsgid=650 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="git-upload-pack" exe="/usr/libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Comment: I'd recommend to take a look at the Q/As under the [selinux] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: congratulations for not [disabling SELinux](http://stopdisablingselinux.com/) and trying instead to understand it and configure it properly.

Filtering the AVC denials you posted in your question makes much more clear what the problem could be:

```
# cat avc_denials | audit2allow

#============= httpd_sys_script_t ==============
allow httpd_sys_script_t gitosis_var_lib_t:dir { read search open getattr };
allow httpd_sys_script_t gitosis_var_lib_t:file { read getattr open ioctl append };
```

The usual method to debug AVC denials, however, makes use of the `ausearch(8)` command:

```
# ausearch -m avc -ts recent | audit2allow
```

Check the manpage for further information on the switches you can use.

With this information, now you know what is happening: the process labeled `httpd_sys_script_t`, possibly the CGI code `gitolite3` uses to publish its repos, is being denied access to files and directories labeled `gitosis_var_lib_t` (the repos) to execute different operations (`read`, `search`, `open`, ...).

Now you should determine whether to grant this access or not. Let's suppose you want to grant access. You would need to create a custom policy module describing the rules defining the access you want to grant. This is more or less simple depending on the complexity of the process:

```
# ausearch -m avc -ts 10:40:00 | audit2allow -m my_gitolite3 > my_gitolite3.te
```

This will produce a `type enforcement` description like this:

```
module my_gitolite3 1.0;

require {
        type httpd_sys_script_t;
        type gitosis_var_lib_t;
        class dir { read search open getattr };
        class file { read getattr open ioctl append };
}

#============= httpd_sys_script_t ==============
allow httpd_sys_script_t gitosis_var_lib_t:dir { read search open getattr };
allow httpd_sys_script_t gitosis_var_lib_t:file { read getattr open ioctl append };
```

You should proceed to review the code to ensure its correctness (in this case, it's simple enough). The next step is to compile the `type enforcement` code into a `module`:

```
# checkmodule -M -m -o my_mygitolite3.mod my_gitolite3.te
```

The module must be packaged into a `policy package` for you to be able to load it and unload it at will:

```
# semodule_package -o my_gitolite3.pp -m my_gitolite3.mod
```

Now, you can load the policy using:

```
# semodule -i my_gitolite3.pp
```

Check it is correctly loaded:

```
# semodule -l | grep my_gitolite3
```

Then, try to trigger the denials again and see if there are more (different) alerts in the audit log regarding this same process.

Further editions of the `type enforcement` code will need the `version` (`1.0`) to be updated, or loading the package will fail. Updating the `policy package` will be done:

```
# semodule -u my_gitolite3.pp
```

There is a lot to learn when starting with SELinux. Some useful references:

- The manpages of the commands
- Check also the output of `apropos selinux`, both `gitosis_selinux` and `httpd_selinux`, will be of interest here

From the RHEL docs

- [Managing Confined Services](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/index.html)
- [Security-Enhanced Linux](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/index.html)

A good introductory presentation by Dave Quigley:

- [Demystifying SELinux](https://speakerdeck.com/dpquigl/demystifying-selinux-as-presented-in-boulder-co-may-6th-2013)

Comment: this is a _very_ nice explanation. I don't know why you've written this out in such detail for this particular question, but I'm grateful. I hope many more people will find this answer. It has helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent answer, this should be the definitive response to any SELinux problem.